# Recursive listing of all objects at an arbitrary depth in a data model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Suppose I have a data structure composed of objects in Python like this:

```
class Planet:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.continents = []

class Continent:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.countries = []

class Country:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.states = []

class State:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cities = []

class City:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now suppose I was to create a function that would be able to take an object and an attribute "path" as parameters and output a list of all the objects that "match" that path. Since I don't really know how to describe very well what I'm thinking of and most likely I'm using the wrong terminology, here is an idea of what it might look like in practice (let's call the function `collect`, and assume that the data structure is populated with data, with `planet` being the "root" object of the data structure):

```
planet = Planet("Earth")
... Code for populating data structure ...

collect(planet, "continents.countries.states.cities")
```

This function call would return a list of every cities in every state in every country in every continent on the planet. Or if I wanted all the states in the data model I would do:

```
collect(planet, "continents.countries.states")
```

Hopefully you get the idea. The problem is that I just have no clue how I would accomplish this. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
def collect(obj, attr_path):
    attrs = attr_path.split(".")
    current_attr = obj
    items = []
    for attr in attrs:
        current_attr = getitem(current_attr, attr)
        # Not sure what to do here...
    return items
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: What you describe is similar to [XPath for XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) or [JSONPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).    There are a couple of JSONPath packages in pypi. I'd suggest you look at them.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do a breadth first search:

```
def bfs(queue, results):
    try:
        obj, attr_path = queue.pop(0)
    except IndexError:
        return

    if attr_path is None:
        results.append(obj)
    else:
        if '.' in attr_path:
            first, rest = attr_path.split('.', maxsplit=1)
        else:
            first, rest = attr_path, None

        children = getattr(obj, first)
        for child in children:
            queue.append((child, rest))

    bfs(queue, results)

def collect(obj, attr_path):
    queue = [(obj, attr_path)]
    results = []
    bfs(queue, results)
    return results
```

Disclaimer: untested